# string abbreviation characters sequence in C

Tags: c

I need to write a function that takes string like "abcdef" and converts it to "a-f", or "589" to "5-9", which functions from stdio.h and string.h can I use for it?

Comment: You don't need *any* functions from those to do it.

Comment: Must the sequence "12" be transformed to "1-2" or let unchanged?

Comment: @tstanisl unchanged

Comment: @ScottHunter Ok tnx

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the start and end of runs. It's easier if you consider every character to be part of a run, so you might runs of length 1 or more.

When you find the end of a run, you need to do different things depending on the length of the run.

- Length of run = 1: Print the only character of the run.
- Length of run = 2: Print both characters of the run.
- Length of run = 3: Print the first and last characters of the run with a dash in between.

With that in mind, we could use the following algorithm:

1. Create a pointer pointing at the first character of the string.
2. While the pointed character isn't NUL,

   1. Print the pointed character.
   2. Set the length of the run to 0.
   3. Loop,

      1. Save the pointed character.
      2. Increment the pointer.
      3. Increment the length of the run.
      4. If the pointed character is NUL,

         1. Break.
      5. If the pointed character isn't one more than the saved character,

         1. Break.
   4. If the length of the run is 2+,

      1. If the length of the run is 3+,

         1. Print a dash.
      2. Print the saved character.
3. Print a line feed.

You should run through the above algorithm on paper, with `"4abcz35xy"` as input. While you do, keep track of the current value of the variables (the pointer, the run length and the saved character).

```
         +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
         |'4'|'a'|'b'|'c'|'z'|'3'|'4'|'5'|'x'|'y'| 0 |
         +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
           ^
Pointer    |
+-------+  |
|     -----+
+-------+

Run length
+-------+
|       |
+-------+

Saved character
+-------+
|       |
+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!

Comment: This wouldn't convert _"589" to "5-9"_.

Comment: @Armali, Correct.